# How to calculate the length of firebase documents?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a chat app but actually I don't have any idea about using firebase with it,

I have created an index field and I want to calculate the length of documents to put their length as an index for every message.

I have got confused really & if you have another way which is better, 
feel free to write it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfOLu.png

Comment: What do you exactly mean by the "length of documents"? Do you mean the number of documents in the `posts`collection?

Comment: do you mean the length of the chat-text ? I wouldnt use indexes if you want to use that for ordering. Use a server-generated timestamp for that and sort by created field with that timestamp.

Comment: length posts collection

Comment: Do you mean the size of the collection containing the documents?  Please be specific, maybe show an example of what you mean.

Comment: the number of documents like the photo (2)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the number of texts that a user has added, I would recommend using a function that is triggered by an update in the collection.

Have another collection, say `chats` that would store the metadata of that chat, like the number of messages, date created etc. You can that increment the number of messages when a message is sent. Also include the `chat id` for the messages sent.

Comment: not sure if that was the posters question but you are definitely right with using server side events in function to do any kind of calculation and summary writes and stuff.

Comment: @Marc yeah just realised I may have misinterpreted the question - my bad. The question was a little vague though...

Comment: "a little" is kind of an understatement ;-) very vague.... indeed.